# Change script tag type to 'text/ecmascript-6' or 'text/babel' when loading modules using requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm trying to use 'text/ecmascript-6' or 'text/babel' as the `type` when having requirejs load the Javascript files using script tags. How can I do that?

For example

```
<script type="text/babel" src="somefile.js"></script>
```

Comment: you can't use a custom _type_ attrib  with a _src_ attrib on a script tag, and still have it load; and the _src_'s url  must contain real javascript. you can however rip the attrib values and feed to to a script loader manually, just use _elm.src_ and _elm.type_ to get the values from the tag.

Comment: @dandavis I am trying to follow these docs here in babeljs https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/browser/ and it mentions to convert es6 javascript to es5 JS I need to set the type to text/babel or text/ecmascript-6. I am using babel as the transpiler

Comment: that would imply having the code inline in the script tag, not linked via _src_. the big difference is that when used with a custom type, inline scripts are essentially unparsed strings, which can be parsed/compiled/transpiled. with an external, it needs to be regular JS. you can probably manuall feed your converter a string from ajax...

Comment: Is there no way to just change the type to quickly test this theory? I understand your point but I think babel probably makes a request to that script using the src and takes it as string and runs it.

Comment: ok ok, i see what you're trying to do now; simulate hard-coded custom tags with requirejs before handing the page off to the transpiler... my hunch is that reqirejs won't support this, but i'll dblcheck for you and replace this comment...

Comment: seems that a _data-requirecontext_ attrib can point to differently configured require context, so you could mix and match regular and custom types. i don't know requirejs deeply, but hopefully this gets you on the right track. if not, it's trivial to make your own script finder and feed your transpiler with it instead of requirejs.

Comment: @dandavis Thanks you definitely helped out. The answer is adding scriptType to your requirejs config object and you were right. It did not work as it did not understand the JS.