# Change script type to "text/babel" using requireJS

Tags: reactjs, requirejs

I am using requireJS to load React components but I was getting the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" because the script type for the file is "text/javascript" instead of "text/babel". To solve this I have tried to set the scriptType as explained by requireJS [docs](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-scriptType) and [explained in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28731256/change-script-tag-type-to-text-ecmascript-6-or-text-babel-when-loading-modul), but I'm unable to get it working or find a good example of how to make this work.

requireConfig.js:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'scripts/',
    paths:
    {
        jquery: 'jquery-1.9.0',
        react: 'libs/build/react',
        reactdom: 'libs/build/react-dom',
        browser: '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min',
        inputWindow: 'inputWindow/inputWindow'
    },
    scriptType: {
        'inputWindow': "text/babel"
     }
});

define(function (require) {
    var InputWindow = require('inputWindow');

    InputWindow.initialize();


});
```

inputWindow.js:

```
define(function(require){

    var React = require('react');
    var ReactDOM = require('reactdom');

    var InputWindow = React.createClass({

        render: function(){
            return(<div>
                {this.props.message}
            </div>)     
        }

    });

    function initialize(){
        ReactDOM.render(<InputWindow message="Hello World!"/>, document.getElementById('inputWindowDiv'))
    }

    return {
        initialize: initialize,
    }
})
```

When I configure requireConfig.js with the section

```
scriptType:{
    'inputWindow':'text/babel'
}
```

then the file inputWindow.js is loaded into index.html with the tag

```
type="[Object Object]"
```

until requireJS times out.

[screen capture of inputWindow.js loaded with type=[Object Object]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAP9t.png)

Comment: Sorry I don't have an answer for you at this time, but I wonder, is requirejs a requirement? I think there are easier ways to load and transpile jsx / react components.

Comment: It is not a requirement but it is a tool that I am familiar with. I'd like to know the answer to this question, even the eventual best answer is to use a different tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
scriptType: {
    'inputWindow': "text/babel"
}
```

try

```
scriptType: 'text/babel'
```

It should work. Right now you're trying to stringify an object so no wonder it doesn't work. ;)

Comment: That works! One thing I'm not sure about is why it only changed the type for the inputWindow file. requirejs still times out loading the file, but I'm thinking that has to do with some other error. The file is loaded with type 'text/babel' before it times out.

Comment: Probably because you wanted to use https://github.com/mikach/requirejs-babel instead of your weird config. :)
Remember to use stubModules for compilation in r.js! Here's how in another plugin for the same thing: https://www.npmjs.com/package/requirejs-babel-plugin